# What is the purpose of Finesse Rogue when core rules state a rogue can take any feat naturally?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rogue

I am rather new to PathFinder and 3.5 in general. I am playing a rogue and running through all the rogue feats I can take and when I came up to Finesse Rogue

> Finesse Rogue: Gain Weapon Finesse as a bonus feat.

I found this confusing since at the end of the rogue feats list is states:

> Feat: A rogue may gain any feat that she qualifies for in place of a rogue talent.

What would be the reason to take Finesse Rogue at all? If I want Weapon Finesse I would just take it at the rogue feat time.

I am sure I am just missing something that makes it more important to take it as Finesse Rogue, I am just not seeing it...

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't have the sourcebook in front of me, but looking at the online d20pfsrd [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents), Finesse Rogue is a basic level Rogue Talent, which become available for taking at 2nd level. The 'Feat' Rogue Talent is listed as an 'Advanced Talent', which isn't available until 10th level. So when a rogue is 10th level, yes, the 'Feat' talent makes the 'Finesse Rogue' talent redundant. But before 10th level that isn't the case.

Comment: Ahh, I see, looking at it on that page makes it make more sense. Looking at it in the core rule book made it look like at any level I could select any feat regardless. Appreciate it!

Comment: A minor note: as @PaulHutton notes on his answer - you **cannot take the same rouge talent twice** - so the "Feat" advanced talent still doesn't render "Finesse Rogue" redundant - its existence allows you to take more than a single feat overall - that's the reason for several other specific feat-talents such as "Combat Trick" and "Combat Swipe"...

Answer (score 14):

A key point you might be missing is this:

> A rogue cannot select an individual talent more than once.

You may want to save the `Feat` talent for a different feat. If so, the `Finesse Rogue` talent is useful.

This applies to other talents, too, such as `Combat Trick` (gain a bonus combat feat).

Comment: You are correct, I did miss that. Or rather, I read that and it didn't click in my head that you would only be able to take "Feat" once. Made me have to change how I was doing things quite a bit.

Comment: Yes, note there are a few exceptions. Oddest to me is the `Ninja Trick`, especially as there is a corresponding `Rogue Talent` in the Ninja trick list; why don't they just share one list? If they could cross-select only once it would make sense, but they explicitly state they can be selected more than once.

Comment: @PaulHutton - It's to allow certain ones to block the other - you can't take a ninja trick with the same name as a rogue talent, and vice versa, so you're stuck with the version you "naturally" get.  Also, a rogue can only take one advanced ninja trick, I think.